# Reset the scrollviewer to its initial position with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, scrollview, reset, page-refresh

I have a Silverlight application, containing a scrollviewer in a grid layout.

When I move the scroller down and  close this grid with the close button, the scroller remains at the bottom whenever I reopen the grid.

Is there a way I can reset the scroller to the top position?

Comment: I am not sure, I understand the question. Are you looking for `scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0d);`?

Comment: ScrollToHome? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltohome.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Hello supriya khamesra,

Please Try this.
Please Put your grid inside scroll viewer and then write your bellow code after grid selection change.

`grdDetail.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0d);`

OR

grdDetail.ScrollToTop();